# How to cross in FIFA 13?

Tags: fifa-13

Every time I cross in FIFA 13 in "seasons" 1v1, I always get the ball blocked by another defender. This always also happens with the opponent, they attempt to cross and they fail because I always have defenders in the box, or I'll just move the goalie out.

How can I make a successful cross in FIFA 13?

Comment: What level are you at in Seasons? What control scheme do you have selected? Crossing is generally considered quite over-powered in FIFA games, so it's odd that you're experiencing this.

Comment: I have played this game for more than a year online and offline, and I very rarely score from a cross. Trying to bring the ball back, and pass to feet is a better strategy to score.

Comment: What team are you? By any chance Barcelona with Messi, Sanchez and Neymar up front who can't head.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all have a striker who's good at heading. Not even that necessary although Ibrahimovic scores way more headers for me than Suarez
- Then make sure you have a fair chance of getting the ball to the
  striker. Don't just cross the ball when the striker isn't in a good position.
- You shouldn't cross too early. It's better to cross when you're at the goal line than crossing when you haven't even reached the length of the penalty area.
- Don't cross while your with the back to the way you want to cross.

Also your running into the position to make a cross is important. DONT run like this:

[image]

Instead run like this:

[image]

Corners are overpowered so I can't see how you can't manage to score with a cross.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking a cross with random amount of power and then landing the ball to the defender's feet you could probably press the cross twice to play a low cross which has a higher probability to reach your striker.
Also taking the ball near to the corner and then playing the cross to the midfielder behind the striker who will then be at the center of the box can volly the incoming cross directly into the net.
As a matter of fact pressing the cross thrice plays a ground cross. Try this too.

Comment: "you could probably press the cross twice to play a low cross which has a higher probability to reach your striker" not true. Really depends on the situation

Comment: ya that's why i used the words "higher probability"